# Why R session aborts in a for loop with 13 K pdf files?

Tags: r, resources, abort, termination

I'm doing for loop for 13 K pdf files, where it reads, pre-processes text, finds similarities and writes in txt. However, when I run the for loop after 760 pdf files, R session aborts. What can be the reason?

1. I tried to write minimal code to reproduce the error. But I receive same issue.
2. I tried to increase `memory_limit()`, it is also not the issue.
3. I tried to delete hidden files in the folder, like `Thumbs.db`, but same issue appears again.
4. I tried to divide 13 K pdf files into 4 folders, each (3,3K), and I got same error message `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : can not open the connection. In addition: There are 50 warnings() and R session aborted.`
5. When I run pdf_folder[759:762], it reads perfectly fine without abort.

```
folder_path <- "C: ...."
## get vector with all pdf names
pdf_folder <- list.files(folder.path)

## for loop over all pdf documents
for(s in 1:length(pdf_folder)){
 # for(s in 1:2){
 tryCatch({


   ## choose one pdf document from vector of strings
   pdf_document_name <- pdf_folder[s]

   ## read pdf_document pdf into data.frame
   pdf <- read_pdf(paste0(folder_path,"/",pdf_document_name))

   print(s)

   rm(pdf)

 ## first end trycatch block
}, error = function(e){print(paste("Error: PDF Document not used: ",pdf_document_name, sep =""))}
 ) ## end of trycatch

} ## end of for loop

# Error: 

Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : can not open the connection. In addition: There are 50 warnings()
```

The expected outcome is to read, pre-process all pdf documents in the folder.path.

Comment: What messages are on the console when R aborts? Is there something unique about the 760th and 761st files that make crashing at the point predictable? In other words, if you change from `1:length(pdf_folder)` to `pdf_folder[759:762]`, does it still crash on the same files? What is your `read_pdf` function doing?

Comment: read_pdf function reads pdf documents as a data.frame.

Messages on the console: Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : can not open the connection. 

In addition: There are 50 warnings()

I checked 760th and 761th nothing special, classic pdf documents.

Comment: Can you please put the text (verbatim in a code block) in the question? It's very relevant to the question, and comments can be missed/skipped/hidden. BTW: *"can not open the connection"* sounds like a filename does not exist. Perhaps you need `list.files(folder.path, full.names=TRUE)` instead (and then no need for `paste0(...)` within `read_pdf`). I wonder if somehow either the `paste0` is munging things just enough, or there's some other path-component being munged/missed.

Comment: The issue of Error was `pdf <- read_pdf(paste0(folder_path,"/",pdf_document_name))`  instead of `"/"` I put `"\\"`.

Comment: Now, after trying ` full.names=TRUE` and `read_pdf(pdf_document_name)` it aborts on 760 again.

Comment: Back to my original suggestions. What happens when you use `pdf_folder[759:762]`?

Comment: +1 @r2evans I had this same issue with .png files (recursive =T,full.names=T) turns out that the file(s) were being appended with ‘~$’ because they were opened by another program. The list.files() was listing the <b>copied<b> file name (‘~$’). Worth a check at the fail point.

Comment: When I run `pdf_folder[759:762]`, it reads perfectly fine without abort.

Comment: What I did -sorry, i know it’s frustrating; add a logic test. I did df$exist<-apply(df,2,file.exist) which gave me a quick way to note the couple of files with nonexistent names

Comment: Bakai, you have some form of resource-exhaustion, it seems. It could be memory or perhaps (less likely) file-descriptors/connections. Is `read_pdf` something you can share? Is it too big? I find it curious that you capture the output as `pdf <- ...` but over-write it on the next pass in the `for` loop, discarding the return value. Are you doing something else there, perhaps `rbind`ing the results into some larger `frame`?

Comment: In addition, I tried to divide 13 K pdf files into 4 folders, each (3,3K), and I got same error message `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : can not open the connection. In addition: There are 50 warnings()` and R session aborted.

Comment: Moreover, I tried to run same code on R console (not Rstudio) it runs without abort. However, it fails in Rstudio.

Comment: Maybe it's keeping the files open and it ran out of file handlers.

Comment: On every iteration of  pdf_document I remove the pdf, `rm(pdf)`.

Comment: Has this been fixed? I have a very similar issue using `readtext::readtext()` on rounabout 120 small PDFs.